# Weird new problem when multiplying or dividing variables within lm() in R

Tags: r

I'm working with some old code for the first time in a few years, and have realized it's broken where is uses lm().  The problem is replicated in this simple example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(1,2,3))
lm(df$y ~ 1/(0.00005 * df$x))
```

Running the above lm() throws an error:

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

I can't figure out why this is happening - can anyone help me?  The code worked last time I used it.  Thanks!

EDIT:  below, akrun suggested I use transform() within lm().  This works in the simple case above, but I'm actually trying to do this within a function like

```
test <- function(bmp, M, Q, c=5e-5)
{ 
bmp.w <- which(bmp <= Q)
if (length(bmp.w) > 1 & length(unique(bmp[bmp.w]))>1)
{
    m <- lm(M[bmp.w] ~ I(1 / (c * (bmp[bmp.w]))))
    return(abs(summary(m)$coefficients[2, c('Estimate', 'Std. Error')]))
} else
{
    return(c(0.5,3))
}
```

How would I use transform() in this function?  I've tried `m <- lm(M[bmp.w] ~ x, data=transform(x=1 / (c * (bmp[bmp.w]))))`, but that does not work.

EDIT2: The easy solution is to just evaluate the term before calling lm(), like

```
test <- function(bmp, M, Q, c=5e-5)
{ 
bmp.w <- which(bmp <= Q)
if (length(bmp.w) > 1 & length(unique(bmp[bmp.w]))>1)
{
    #m <- lm(M[bmp.w] ~ I(1 / (c * (bmp[bmp.w]))))
    gah <- 1 / (c * (bmp[bmp.w]))
    m <- lm(M[bmp.w] ~ I(gah))
    return(abs(summary(m)$coefficients[2, c('Estimate', 'Std. Error')]))
} else
{
    return(c(0.5,3))
}
```

but this doesn't solve how to include transform().

Answer (score 3):

We can do this outside i.e specify the formula as `y ~ x`, but change 'x' value in `transform` and pass that into `data` argument

```
lm(y ~ x, data = transform(df, x = 1/(0.00005 * x)))
#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ x, data = transform(df, x = 1/(5e-05 * x)))

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)            x  
#  3.6923077   -0.0001385
```

Comment: Thanks for this.   Can you explain why it's necessary to do this outside?  (Especially when it used to work the way I posted above).  Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas It is evaluating the column name and you don't have a column with name`1/(0.00005 * x`

Comment: Thanks, but why does this work if I use 1/(1*x)?  Also, why did the code previously work a couple of years ago?

Comment: @Thomas If you check the output.  it is different `lm(df$y ~ 1/(1 * df$x))` and `lm(y ~ x, data = transform(df, x = 1/x))`

Comment: OK, I see that.  I am trying to use this in a function, but it's not working, I think because I don't have a df to enter in transform().  How would I use transform() in this function:

test <- function(bmp, M, Q, c=5e-5)
{
  
  
  
 bmp.w <- which(bmp <= Q)
  if (length(bmp.w) > 1 & length(unique(bmp[bmp.w]))>1)
  {
    m <- lm(M[bmp.w] ~ I(1 / (c * (bmp[bmp.w]))))
    return(abs(summary(m)$coefficients[2, c('Estimate', 'Std. Error')]))
  } else
  {
    return(c(0.5,3))
  }
  
}

I tried m <- lm(M[bmp.w] ~ x, data=transform(x=1 / (c * (bmp[bmp.w])))), but that does not work.

Comment: @Thomas Can you update it your post as it is hard to copy/paste from the comments

Answer (score 3):

You can always use `I`:

```r
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(1,2,3), idx = 3:1)
lm(y ~ I(1/(0.00005 * x)), df)
#R> 
#R> Call:
#R> lm(formula = y ~ I(1/(5e-05 * x)), data = df)
#R> 
#R> Coefficients:
#R>      (Intercept)  I(1/(5e-05 * x))  
#R>        3.6923077        -0.0001385  

lm(y ~ I(1/(0.00005 * x[idx])), df)
#R> 
#R> Call:
#R> lm(formula = y ~ I(1/(5e-05 * x[idx])), data = df)
#R> 
#R> Coefficients:
#R>           (Intercept)  I(1/(5e-05 * x[idx]))  
#R>             0.3076923              0.0001385
```

From `?I`:

> In function `formula`. There it is used to inhibit the interpretation of operators such as "`+`", "`-`", "`*`" and "`^`" as formula operators, so they are used as arithmetical operators. This is interpreted as a symbol by `terms.formula`.

#### Notes

In the above, I use the `data` argument of `lm` is:

> an optional data frame, list or environment (or object coercible by `as.data.frame` to a data frame) containing the variables in the model. If not found in data, the variables are taken from `environment`(`formula`), typically the environment from which `lm` is called.

This way you can use `transform` on a `data.frame` and pass it to the `data` argument of `lm` like [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64995619/5861244).

Comment: Thanks!  The old version of the code I'm using (see EDIT in my original post).  I seem to be having a problem with that.  Anyway, I solved it the easy way be just doing the calculation before the lm() command.  :)